# Cycling through 3 outputs on clock pulse component choice

Tags: digital-logic, counter, component-selection

Is there a better way to cycle through 3 outputs in a loop on clock input?
I'm currently using a CD4017 with the 4th counter tied back to reset, and this does work well enough.

The fact that it is a single IC is a plus for me here, it seems like I'm not doing something right though with only using a third of the decade counter. I haven't been able to find anything like a half decade counter or the like when searching through digikey components.

Appreciate any thoughts on the matter.

[image: Counter circuit with CD4017]

Comment: you say 4017, but you are using a 4022 model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything "wrong" using the 4017 connected like that.  You might be able to use some flip-flops connected together or a shift register to get the same functionality, but there would be no savings in pin count or complexity.  You could use a 6- or 8-pin microcontroller with a few lines of code on it, which would also enable you to include some additional functionality and maybe eliminate the need for some other parts of your circuit.

Comment: Linked flip flops had been an earlier consideration that I had dropped for exactly that reason of complexity and pin count. I hadn't considered a smaller microcontroller though. That's an interesting idea, and I think I could save space even with having the programming pads. Much appreciated.